# Macroscopic quantumness and decoherence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, decoherence

Can somebody suggest a "measure" that aims at mathematically defining a "macroscopic quantum state" which is compatible with decoherence or the thought "macroscopicity = states that are especially vulnerable for decoherence by the environment"? Since my master thesis (teacher education) is about decoherence regarding macroscopic states (e.g. Schrödingers cat), I'd like to focus rather on one "measure" that fits the topic of my thesis. Unfortunately I'm by far no expert regarding this topic.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's a subject of active research.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to quantify how well a given state of a given object does or doesn't avoid becoming entangled with the environment in a given model? If so, then what about something like the rate of increase of the entanglement entropy? (I'm not saying that's a perfect measure, but a thesis could describe its pros and cons.)

Comment: Yes that's what I am looking for. Just some ideas to make understandable, what "macroscopic quantumness" could or can mean. Thank you for this idea!

Comment: not a measure, but people often use Leggett-Garg as a way to "certify macrorealism". See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leggett%E2%80%93Garg_inequality and references therein